# How to configure suppress ParameterNumber on checkstyle?

Tags: checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

How to configure to suppress the number of parameter (ParameterNumber) on checkstyle:

Checkstyle configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
        <version>9.1</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <configLocation>/config/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
      <suppressionsLocation>/config/checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
      <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

checkstyle-suppressions.xml file:

```
<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="ParameterNumber" files="src/main/java/org/acme/Signal.java" />
</suppressions>
```

I still got the message:

```
Signal.java:[247,26] (sizes) ParameterNumber: More than 7 parameters (found 15).
```

Answer (score 0):

https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_filters.html#SuppressionFilter

> Location of the file defined in file property is checked in the
> following order:
>
> ```
> as a filesystem location
> if no file found, and the location starts with either http:// or https://, then it is interpreted as a URL
> if no file found, then passed to the ClassLoader.getResource() method.
> ```

Use the package exactly is in java:

```
<suppress 
  checks="ParameterNumber"
  files="org.acme.Signal.java" />
```